# Check the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1/n} \sqrt {x}/ (1+x^{2})dx$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Check the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1/n}\frac{\sqrt {x}}{1+x^{2}}\;dx$$

I think to solve this problem, first, I need to solve this integral. Then I will have this series in terms of n. Then convergence can be checked. 
But, I couldn't get this integral in form of $n$.

How can I solve this$?$

Comment: I guess you mean $\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\frac 1 n} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2}dx$, right?

Comment: Yes, I edited it.

Comment: Use $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2} \leq \sqrt{x}$ valid on $[0,1]$ to bound the general term (evaluate the integral and do a comparison test).

Comment: I don't think the problem intends to have you solve the integral first (the answer to the integral is not an easy one, essentially anti-derivative of $\sqrt{\tan x}$). As Winther suggested, you should try comparison.

Comment: You don't need the exact value of the integral, for such problems like this, in general. You need an estimate -- an overestimate to prove convergence, or an underestimate to show divergence.

Comment: Another suggestion: if we denote $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{\{0<x\le \frac 1n\}}=[\#\text{ of $n$ such that $x\in (0,1/n]$}]$, then $0\le f(x)\le 1/x$ and $$\sum_n \int_0^{\frac 1 n} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2}dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt x f(x)}{1+x^2}dx \le \int_0^1 \frac 1{\sqrt x (1+x^2)} dx =\int_0^1 \frac{2 dx}{1+x^4}<\infty.$$

Comment: I have a similar problem to check the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{n}^{n+1} e^{-x^{1/2}} dx$. I just need a function with which I can compare it. I couldn't find any suitable function for this one.

Comment: $ e^{-\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{x}}} \le \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x} + \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3!}+ \frac{x^2}{4!}} \le \frac{4!}{4!+x^2}$, and for $x \in [n,n+1]$ we have $\frac{4!}{4!+x^2} \le \frac{4!}{4!+n^2}$, so our series $\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4!}{4!+n^2}$ (I assumed $x \ge 1$ in that inequality)

Comment: Thanks @Dominik Kutek

Answer (score 3):

Note, that for $x \in [0,\frac{1}{n}]$ we have $ \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2} \le \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} $.

$$\text{So }\int_0^{\frac{1}{n}} \frac{\sqrt x}{1+x^2} \le \int_0^{\frac{1}{n}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} = \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

So by comparison (since terms are positive) our series $\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{3}{2}}$, which converge